# (Azure Functions) How can I change the memory size

Tags: azure-functions

I'd created an Azure Functions instance for 128MB memory size.
Then, I noticed there is no way in order to change the memory size.

I cannot change it after creation? Or is there any way?

Answer (score 8):

This setting is no longer necessary, as the memory usage is now calculated dynamically. Please see [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/11/15/making-azure-functions-more-serverless/) for details.